# array working in localhost but not on server

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, error-handling

I am working on a client side survey app for which i require a lot of urls of images and ids from my server, i got my images fro rails console of our site in array format.

My code is

```
<?php
$links=[[64, "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__4_.jpg"], [63, "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__1_.jpg"], [62, "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__2_.jpg"], [61, "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__7_.jpg"], [60, "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__5_.jpg"]; //and 200  more images//

$n=(count($links));

for($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    echo $links[$i][0].'->'.$links[$i][1]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

It works cool on my localhost but when i push on to server its showing an error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /srv/disk4/1225087/www/dcvit.co.nf/survey.php on line 25"

Comment: One thing I noticed, in your for loop, $i <= $n; should be $i < $n.

Comment: You're using new syntax of array which is only support by php 5.4 or newer. Make sure your live server supports php 5.4 or newer.

Comment: i will check if the version has php5+ and why cant i use <=$n, i need that logic... why not??? whats the logical error in it???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server is not running the required php version 5.4 for the [] notation for the arrays.

So you have to refer to using the array().

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$links= array(
        64  => "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__4_.jpg",
        63  => "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__1_.jpg",
        62  => "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__2_.jpg",
        61  => "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__7_.jpg",
        60  => "https://oyo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/hotel_image/9/photo__5_.jpg"
        );

foreach($links as $k => $link)
{
    echo $k . '->' . $link . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Again, $i <= $n should be: $i < $n.

Comment: You don't need to specify that with foreach.

Comment: Ah, my bad, the code in this answer has been updated.

Comment: thanks alot... i will check if my server has the latest version of php... my localhost has the latest php....